# Ответы на вопросы заведомо не подходящие для СО

Tags: обсуждение

К примеру есть вопросы когда люди просят что то сделать за них. И таких много и некоторые отвечают на такие вопросы. К примеру [Очистка массива php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552854/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-php) . Почему? Не ужели вы хотите СО превратить в бесплатный фриланс? Или вы думаете что циферки около ника что то значат для вас?  Еще один пример такого вопроса [Организация системы управления MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552831/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-mysql?noredirect=1#comment711712_552831) люди даже не пытаться что то сделать...

Comment: Хочу напомнить, что минусы на вопросах - бесплатны. Если лично вам не нравится какой-то вопрос - смело минусуйте.

Comment: @PashaPash суть этого вопроса для обсуждения факт того что люди на них отвечают. Суть того вопроса в том что люди публикают вопросы задачи а нет подходящего пункта в тревоге. Где вы видите дубликат?

Comment: Если честно - совсе не понял суть этого вопроса. Да, люди на них отвечают. Если вопрос - онтопик, никто не может запретить участнику на него ответить. В чем вы видите проблему?

Comment: @Naumov Смирись и минусуй)) На ruSO все правила двояки и, в принципе, не соблюдаются. Один подобный вопрос заплюсуют и кучу ответов наваляют, другой закроют, как не соответствующий правилам. Или вот надо бы по правилам дубли закрывать, но, между тем, чем больше однотипных вопросов с разной формулировкой, тем больше шанс найти что-то подходящее и не стоит закрывать... так что....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я минусую просто охото как то обратиться к людям которые отвечают на такие вопросы, что стоит не отвечать на такой вопрос а подтолкнуть автора к изучению материала.

Comment: @Naumov увы, не получится. Только если сделать собственный ресурс с блекджеком и .....своим кровавым режимом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский футорама  :D